# android: gradle product flavors messing up minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I've an Android app which min sdk level is 15, but from 15 to 18 i need to import extra libraries in order to make it work.

To do that i'm using "flavor" on gradle build file as the following snippet

```
   minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 124
    versionName "3.4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
    flavorDimensions "api"
    productFlavors {
        older {
            dimension "api"
            minSdkVersion 15
            maxSdkVersion 18
            versionCode 1 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode

        }
        newer {
            dimension "api"
            minSdkVersion 19
            versionCode android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
```

the thing is after adding this flavor feature Android Studio doesn't allow me to run it on emulator sdk level 15 - 18.

[image]

but prior before it worked fine, i just splited the 2 flavors because the "extra api" needed to make the app works in older versions makes it grows twice the size, so i wanted the newer smartphones to avoid this extra overhead

how can i keep the two flavors building and still run on emulators ?

Comment: You need to select which build flavor you want to use. Check the `Build` tab.

Comment: what to check on build tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to

**Build** -> **Select Build Variant...**

A window that looks something like this should appear in the left sidebar:

[image]

Use the dropdown to select the `older` flavor. Use the button in the top right of that window to close it and then try running it again.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not the answer you are looking for but I don't use a min SDK before 19. Ice Cream Sandwich (15) came out in 2011.

By dropping SDK 18 and lower you only lose an additional 3.5% of potential users for your app. If your app is currently in the store you can even check what versions on average use your app. That being said, perhaps in your specific situation it is more important to cater to the entire market, even the 3.8% of users below SDK 19.

[Here is a list of version usage](https://fossbytes.com/most-popular-android-versions-always-updated/)

Comment: first, these 3.5% is an average into worlds statistics account by millions of europeans and americans which switch their phones everytime they changes clothes to match it... my app aims south american market, i do have many lvl 15 users...